# Proof of Extended Law of the Mean (Taylor's Formula)

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, nonlinear-optimization

I started reading "The Mathematics of nonlinear Programming - AL peressini" recently.

**Theorem : Suppose that $f(x) , f'(x) ,f''(x)$ exist on the closed interval $[a,b]$. If $x^* ,x $ are two different points of $[a,b]$ , then there exists a point $z$ strictly between $x^*$ and $x$ such that**

$$f(x)=f(x^*)+f'(x^*)(x-x^*)+\frac{f''(z)}{2}(x-x^*)^2$$

I tried to prove this theorem using The Fundamental theorem of calculus. But I can not stop it at the second derivative . Do I have to use mean value theorem ? or is there a simple proof for this ?

Comment: Am I missing something here, or is this not just Taylor's theorem with the remainder term given for the second derivative term?

Comment: I think that's it. Exactly the answer given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219577/mean-value-theorem-for-the-second-derivative

Comment: @AlexisOlson Can you explain the proof please ? I do not understand the conversation in your tagged question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$F(t)=f(t)-f(x^*)-f'(x^*)(t-x^*)-K(t-x^*)^2$$

where let's set K such that $$0=f(x)-f(x^*)-f'(x^*)(x-x^*)-K(x-x^*)^2$$

So we know that $F(x)=0$ and $F(x^*)=0$

By Rolle's rule, there is a $c1 \in (x, x^*)$ such that $F'(c1)=0$

Now look at the derivative $$F'(t) = f'(t) - f'(x^*)-K \cdot 2(t-x^*)$$

We know  $F'(x^*)=0$ and $F'(c1)=0$, so again applying Rolle's theorem, there is a  $c2 \in (c1, x^*) \subset (x, x^*)$ such that $F''(c2)=0$

$$F''(t) = f''(t) -2K$$ Therefore $$F''(c2)=0 \rightarrow  f''(c2) -2K=0$$

This gives $K=f''(c2)/2$ and you can complete the proof.